# Error with org-babel-execute-buffer

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I'm using Org mode 9.2.3 and Emacs 26.2.

When I try to execute all source blocks of an org document with `org-babel-execute-buffer` (bound to `C-C C-v b`), I always get the following error message:

> Symbol's definition function is void: org-outline-overlay-data

I'm not sure I'm uderstanding. According to the [release notes of Org mode 9.2](https://orgmode.org/Changes.html), this function has been removed and replaced by `org-save-outline-visibility`.

Is this a bug I should report, or am I missing something?

Thanks!

EDIT: The `org` package has been installed through the Package Menu Buffer, using the GNU repository. I could indeed have two versions of `org` that are in conflict, since I can see that both org 9.1.9 ('built-in') and org 9.2.3 are displayed in the package menu buffer.

Comment: You probably have a "mixed" installation where an old version of org-mode is interfering with the current version. How you resolve it depends on how you installed your current version. Please edit the question and describe how you installed org-mode.

Comment: Indeed, this could be the problem... The org package has been installed through the Package Menu Buffer, using the GNU repository. I could indeed have two versions of org that are in conflict, since I can see that both org 9.1.9 ('built-in') and org 9.2.3 are displayed in the package menu buffer.
However, I can also read in the package manu buffer that org 9.2.3 "is shadowing a built-in package".

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved.**
I found this info on org website:

> **Using Emacs packaging system**
>
> Recent Emacs distributions include a packaging system which lets you
>   install Elisp libraries. You can install Org with 
>   `M-x package-install RET org`.
>
> **Important**: You need to do this in a session where no ‘.org’ file has been visited, i.e., where no Org built-in function have been
>   loaded. Otherwise autoload Org functions will mess up the
>   installation.

Indeed, I might have installed org when some org files had already been visited with the "old" 9.1.9 version. I just reinstalled Emacs and all the packages, and this solved the problem.

Thanks!